# Hive sql:select out all the ids that spend more than 0 each month

Tags: sql, hive

How to select out all the ids that spend more than 0 each month? 
Here id 1 spent more than 0 every month and will be chosen.

```
+----+--------+-------+
| id | date  | spend |
+----+--------+-------+
|  1 | 201801 |     1 |
|  2 | 201801 |     2 |
|  3 | 201801 |     0 |
|  1 | 201802 |     3 |
|  2 | 201802 |     4 |
|  3 | 201802 |     0 |
|  1 | 201803 |     5 |
|  2 | 201803 |     0 |
|  3 | 201803 |     0 |
|  1 | 201804 |     8 |
|  2 | 201804 |     2 |
|  3 | 201804 |     0 |
+----+--------+-------+
```

Comment: What did you mean when you said `every months`? Did you mean every months that appear on your table, or every months between two define months?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use aggregation and `having`:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(spend) > 0
```